# Format of Letter of guarantee for Belgium visa

Tags: visas, belgium

I am visiting Belgium to attend a study related conference. My professor will act as guarantor to cover all expenses. What should be mentioned in the letter of guarantee by him such that the visa does not get rejected. Should any other documents related to the professor also be enclosed while writing the letter?

Comment: What is your nationality? How long is the conference and are you attending only or presenting? Is your professor acting as a sponsor in a personal capacity?

Comment: 3 days.Attending too. Personal capacity

Comment: Can you quote the exact wording of the Consulate’s request? As a general guide, a personal sponsor will need to state why they are prepared to sponsor you and what their relationship is to you, and to provide documentary evidence to substantiate their ability to support you eg evidence of salary, savings. Having a sponsor does not guarantee that your visa will be approved. As an aside, since it appears you will be travelling together, does your professor already have a visa for Belgium or are you both applying now?

Comment: The exact wording is as follows "guarantee to cover all costs that may arise during the stay in Belgium". Both of us (me and professor) are applying now for the visa.

Comment: @Giorgio Answer added

Answer (score 2):

As a general guide, a personal sponsor will need to state why they are prepared to sponsor you and what their relationship is to you, and to provide documentary evidence to substantiate their ability to support you eg salary, savings. Having a sponsor does not guarantee your visa will be approved.

Comment: It is probably too late to address the OP's specific situation now, but based on the question and comments I rather doubt the professor was really acting as a personal sponsor. It seems much more likely they were paying for the trip out of a research grant or something. (And to top that off, the OP also seems to have gotten the whole thing mixed up with requirements for a Verpflictungserklärung-like guarantee).

Comment: The professor had written on his letterhead that he acted as a guarantor for all expenses. It was accepted